# How to release(dealloc)AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: objective-c, avaudioplayer

I'll be looping a song and when a new view appears, will be stopping it then dealloc it, alloc/init a new instance of AVAudioPlayer then play some other song for the new view.

Would it be more efficient for me to just change the song with the same instance of AVAudioPlayer? (If that's possible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you reuse the same instance you have to re-initialize it with `initWithContentsOfURL...` or `initWithData...` for it to play a different song, so its probably the same thing you are doing.

Comment: Ok so then how do I release the instance then..? I tried to find something like [self.player remove]; but no...

Comment: Do I just nil it? self.player = nil; ?

Comment: You don't have to explicitly release it, ARC will handle that automatically. `self.player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWith...]` should do.